# Sengrid getenv() functon inside queue (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, email, environment-variables, sendgrid

Hey I am using Sendgrid in my Laravel project. I send mail from controller easily bu getting apikey like that : `$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));`
but when I call this function from laravel queue, this getenv returns null.. what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `env()` instead of `getenv()`? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel's latest versions, I think env doesn't work like this anymore. you should use `\Config::get("file.value")` in which file is the name of the config file in /configs folder,  value is the variable which resides in this filename.